# How to write objects in a file using arraylist

Tags: java, file

**I want to write objects in a file by using arraylist, what should i add to display my file?**

```
package my.issues.issue15;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WriteObjects {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Result r1 = new Result("101","science","3","A");
        Result r2 = new Result("102"," Nationhood Studies","3","B+");
        Result r3 = new Result("103","Math","3","A-");

        ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        resultList.add(r1);
        resultList.add(r2);
        resultList.add(r3);
        System.out.println(resultList);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Course.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos =new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(resultList);

        System.out.println("Finish");

        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    }


}
```

**It shows error if i use the buffer writer. What should i add so that my file will be able to display?**

```
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Results.txt"), true));
            writer.write(resultList);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Error**

```
Error:(21, 19) java: no suitable method found for write(java.util.ArrayList<my.issues.issue15.Result>)
    method java.io.Writer.write(char[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<my.issues.issue15.Result> cannot be converted to char[])
    method java.io.Writer.write(java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<my.issues.issue15.Result> cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
    method java.io.BufferedWriter.write(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<my.issues.issue15.Result> cannot be converted to int)
```

**Below are the details of my Result class. i would like to figure out what should i add so that the file will be created**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Result implements Serializable {
    private String courseCode;
    private String courseName;
    private String creditHours;
    private String grade;

    public Result(String courseCode, String courseName, String creditHours, String grade) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.creditHours = creditHours;
        this.grade = grade;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "< " + courseCode + " | " + courseName + " | " + "Credit Hours: " + creditHours + " | " + "Grade: " +grade + " >";
    }
}
```

Comment: "it shows error" - what error? Add the stacktrace to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call `write(...)` which expects either a char array, a String or an Integer as parameter (The error message literally tells you "`ArrayList<...> cannot be converted to char[]/String/int`).

Since I don't know how your `Result` class looks like, I can't write the code for you, but basically you need to get the Values from each Result object and either write them to File one by one or use a `StringBuilder` to build the full String that you want to write.

It would probably look something like this:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(Result result : resultList)
{
    String[] resultData = result.getValues(); // getValues() is whatever getters you use in result class
    
    for(String substring : resultData)
    {
        sb.append(substring)
    }
}
```

And then you can call `toString()` on the StringBuilder instane and write that to your file.

Nevermind it's way simpler than that, all you need to do is call `toString()` on the ArrayList.

Full class:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WriteObjects
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Result r1 = new Result("101", "science", "3", "A");
        Result r2 = new Result("102", " Nationhood Studies", "3", "B+");
        Result r3 = new Result("103", "Math", "3", "A-");
        
        ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        resultList.add(r1);
        resultList.add(r2);
        resultList.add(r3);
        System.out.println(resultList);
        
        try
        {
            File file = new File("Results.txt");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            writer.write(resultList.toString());
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I include the BufferedWriter as well?